Open appium inspector programatically with pre-filled parameters
I have appium inspector installed on my mac and I wonder if it would be possible to programatically open it in a way that I could pre-fill required values in the GUI? If yes any hint how to achieve that?
Sincerely

I believe that currently, Appium Inspector does not support pre-filling values in its GUI when the App is launched.
If you are using Appium Inspector with the Appium server for test automation, you can configure the desired values directly within your Appium test scripts.

Well noted, thanks for the feedback.
